# Can we generate electricity by using rotation of wheel of a bicycle?

Tags: electromagnetism, everyday-life, electromagnetic-induction

Can we generate electricity by using rotation of wheel of a bicycle ?

Comment: How will you cause the wheel to rotate? if this is as you are riding OK, but are you trying to make a generator driven by wind or water or something?

Comment: By pedaling, we can generate electrical energy from mechanical energy. Using Faraday's law of electromagnetic induction, a generator can be created. Decades back, bicycles used to have a light bulb infront of them which glowed when pedaled.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows a lack of prior research

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a Dynamo that convert part of he mechanical force - the mouvement - into electricity. 
The Dynamo uses a rotating magnet that create electric current into coils or vice versa. A moving coil around a fixed magnet induce a current into the coil that opposes the mouvement and breaks.
Dynamo uses the law of induction of Faraday.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction
You can buy a Dynamo anywhere in bike shops or in online stores.